# wrong username/ password error-handling using httparty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, error-handling, httparty

I am creating a local gem utilizing httparty to connect to specific website to get auth token. I was able to get the program to fetch auth_token when I entered the correct email and password. However, if I put the wrong email/password, it returns: `NameError: uninitialized constant Gemname::InvalidStudentCodeError`

```
require 'httparty'
class Gemname
  include HTTParty

  def initialize(email, password)
    response = self.class.post("https://www.website.io/api/v1/sessions", body: {"email": email, "password": password})
#####error-handler#####
    if StandardError
      puts "invalid email/pass"
    end
#######################
    @auth_token = response["auth_token"]
  end
end
```

It seems like most errors are categorized under [standard error](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty/blob/master/lib/httparty/exceptions.rb).

The idea is to run from irb `Gemname.new('email', 'wrong-password')`, it would return `"Wrong email/password"`. How should I handle the error to display the proper message?

Edit:
I tried these codes on initialize:

```
if StandardError
  "error"
end
```

I also tried

created on lib folder, a folder named gemname -> error.rb
error.rb:

```
class InvalidStudentCodeError < StandardError
  def initialize(msg="invalid email or password")
    super(msg)
  end
end
```

and on initialize:

```
raise InvalidStudentCodeError.new() if response.code == 401
```

Comment: Can you show the complete code of the method?

Comment: @NicNilov edited - added the code lines I tried

Answer (score 0):

The following raise method solved it:

```
 def initialize(email, password)
    response = self.class.post("https://www.website.io/api/v1/sessions", body: {"email": email, "password": password})
    raise "invalid email/pass, bud" if response.code != 200
    @auth_token = response["auth_token"]
  end
```